# func(" ") causes "call of overloaded QChar(const char[2]) is ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt

Can tell me why the code below causes this error :

```
call of overloaded 'QChar(const char[2])' is ambiguous
```

and the code :

```
void func(QChar a) {
    qDebug() << a;
}

void main() {
    func(" ");
}
```

When `String.remove(QChar,Qt::CaseSensitive)` works : `a.remove(" ");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a string literal (`" "`), which is of type `const char[2]` (one element containing the space, and another one for the terminating `\0`). You want to pass a char literal, written with single quotes: `func(' ')`.

The `QString::remove()` function is overloaded for both strings and single characters. Even in that case, you want to pass a char literal `' '`, which is more efficient than `" "` (the latter implies a call to `strlen()`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to write

```
void main() {
  func(' ');
}
```

Seems like compiler thinks that you passing `const char*` not a `char` because of double quotes.
And there is no constructor for `QChar` from `const char*`.

Comment: No, there's no `QChar(const char*)`.

Comment: @mmutz: Oh, I meant to write "no", just misspelled. Thanks for correction.